# Hyper parameter optimization for network with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, keras

Is there any efficient way I can optimise this neural network..

```
map = {}
for batch in xrange(1,100,1):
    for lr in np.arange(0.00001,1,0.0000001):
        for decay in np.arange(0.0000001,1,0.0000001):
            for momentum in np.arange(0.001,1,0.01):
                print 'batch_' + str(batch) + '_lr_' + str(lr) + '_decay_' + str(decay) + '_momentum_' + str(momentum)
                result = model(batch,lr,decay,momentum)
                print result
                map['batch_' + str(batch) + '_lr_' + str(lr) + '_decay_' + str(decay) + '_momentum_' + str(momentum)] = result

np.save('sgd_opt.npy', map)
```

It is currently being done using multiple for loops -  aren't there anyother efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, one thing that definitely will make the difference is that you don't need to test 9 million different learning rates. Take larger steps.

Comment: @aryamccarthy suggestions? lr is passed ti sgd optimizers.

Comment: That is my suggestion: You test 10^7 learning rates, 10^7 decays, and 10^2 momentums, together. That's way too many. You're assessing 10^16 different models. Let's *generously* say your model only takes 0.3 seconds to train and test. Then it'll take **1.5 million years** to test all combinations. Test fewer combinations, perhaps using `np.logspace`.

Comment: @aryamccarthy sorry.. i didn't complete my sentence..  Do you have any suggestions on ranges to test for.. because yes your are right this is not efficient in anyway..

Comment: there are packages for this kind of thing, look up hyperas

Comment: @chris I tried hyperas it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test fewer combinations. Use [`np.logspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) instead of `np.arange`.

```
for lr in np.logspace(1E-5, 1, 6):  # Tests 1E-5, 1E-4, ..., 1
```

There's likely not much difference in learning rate between, say, 0.00012 and 0.00013. You don't need to test all of those.

If you want to test more than 6 learning rates, go ahead. This gets you a nice spread, and you should do the same for your decay and momentum. You can test 6 learning rates, 6 decays, and 3 momentums (108 combinations altogether) and get likely the same benefit as from the millions of millions of steps your original code uses.

Comment: Maybe add `np.log10()` to ensure that the ranges are the wanted ranges, and not altered by the base multiplication.